# Python, Paramiko Trying to Run a Remote Command

Tags: python, pycharm

Learning `python`:

Here's what I'm doing:

`PyDev` console: starting.

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/home/username/SpiderOak Hive/VirtualEnvs-Python/server_inventory2wiki'])

Python 3.5.3 (default, May 10 2017, 15:05:55) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux
    import paramiko

    user = "ec2-user"
    host = "ec2-35-165-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    key_file = "/home/skeer/Downloads/pythontarget.pem"
    ssh.connect(hostname = host, username = user, key_filename = key_file)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command ('uname -a')
    print stdout.read()
      File "<input>", line 1
        print stdout.read()
               ^
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command ('ifconfig')
    print stdout.read()
      File "<input>", line 1
        print stdout.read()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but the `exec_command` actually does nothing.

Comment: python 3.x changes the print statement to print() function. Check this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Comment: Asked some co-workers about this, it was suggested to use a print function like this: print(stdout.read())